# Can a JSON file be used as database?

Tags: json, database, filter

Theorically i have a group (2000 - 3000) of data structure it's a local obituary project, with 5 item/value for each (name, birth, death, function, photo url) and i want :

- to load this data in html page,
- format each data into styled div,
- allow user to filter (name, function etc) these divs (hide/show) via js or jquery and inputs

i know the best way to do this is mysql + php, but since i have no knowledge yet in this field My question is :

- Is it correct to use a json file to store these data and populate divs ?
- can we filter json data with jquery ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define database.  Can it be used to store data?  Yes.  But it has no search abilities, it isn't ACID compliant, and accessing it would run in the current process. Any non-trivial filtering would require an O(N) process, unless you're going to build index tables in memory. It would also be nearly impossible to keep in sync across processes/machines if the user is allowed to edit any of the data at all.  If its read only and N is small, it can work.  If N is not small or you need to be able to update it, a JSON file is a bad idea.

Comment: For my case i have an already win32 application that can fill the json file with data, i can add a field index for each set and my webpage will only read these data and display them in styled div,

Comment: @Stalkium So you're going to spend a lot of time and effort to reproduce what you get out of a database for free.  I mean, you can do it, it will technically work.  I wouldn't suggest it.  The time you spend learning how to use SQL will be repaid many times over your life of programming, it's used constantly.  And you don't need php, you just need a web service which can be written in any language including javascript with Node.js.  I'd recommend learning how to use a db over hacking in a half solution.

Comment: I will go for your suggest , that's motivating, thanks, i already started to learn how to connect to db via firedac (delphi) which my upload app is built under, thanks